# Mysql Selects in nested loops

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have a table named as `People`:

```
id | name |parent_id
---+------+---------
1  | John | 0
2  | Jane | 1
3  | James| 1
4  | Jack | 0
5  | Jim  | 4
6  | Jenny| 4
```

So john is parent of Jane and James. Tree goes like this.

```
John
-Jane
-James
Jack
-Jim
-Jenny
```

I want to make a table that seems like

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">John</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-</td><td>Jane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-</td><td>James</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Jack</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-</td><td>Jim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-</td><td>Jenny</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

To do this, I use two sql queries. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
<?php

$firstQuery = 'SELECT id, name FROM People WHERE parent_id = 0';

start creating the table

while ($rowP = $result_parent->fetch())
{
    //get the child rows using the second query in the loop:

    $secondQuery = 'SELECT id, name FROM People WHERE parent_id = $rowP["id"]';

    start creating table rows for child items.

    while ($rowC = $result_child->fetch())
    {
        add names into the table belonging the current parent person
    }
}

?>
```

So the problem rises here.

1. This is very bad approach in the performance asppect. What is the correct way.
2. When I try to use the parent person's id as a parameter for the child people query, I get error about `bind_param()` function.
3. This can be done only one SQL query with `JOIN` operation. But I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem:

So the basic idea is about using `fetch()` method in a `while` loop. Instead, I get the all resultset before the loop then use a new instance of it in a `foreach` loop:

```
<?php   
    $firstQuery = 'SELECT id, name FROM People WHERE parent_id = 0';

    $resultP->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $resultP = $db->exec($firstQuery);

    $rowP = $resultP->fetchAll();

    $foreach($rowP as $rp)
    {
        //get the child rows using the second query in the loop:

        $secondQuery = 'SELECT id, name FROM People WHERE parent_id = :p1';

        //start creating table rows for child items.

        $resultP = $db->prepare($secondQuery);

        $resultP->bindValue(':p1', $rp["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $resultP->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $resultP->exeecute();

        $rowC = $resultC->fetchAll();

        $foreach($rowC as $rc)
        {
            //add names into the table belonging the current parent person
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is very bad approach in the performance asppect. What is the correct way.

it is actually not.
A few primary key lookups will never do any harm.

> When I try to use the parent person's id as a parameter for the child people query, I get error about bind_param() function.

First of all, you have not just *mention* the error message but **read** and **comprehend** it, as well as provide it here, full and uncut.

Next, for this one it is quite easy to guess though. Use `store_result()`

> This can be done only one SQL query with JOIN operation. But I don't know how to do.

A canonical text which even has been a part of mysql official docs once: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (first result on google, btw)

Comment: I know that page but did not figure out something for my problem.