# Mysql Adjacency List Model, My query result is not what I want

Tags: mysql, sql

Yesterday, I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856163/mysql-selects-in-nested-loops) question. I decided to change my approach and tried something new. Before starting please look at my table structure below.

I have a table named as `People`:

```
id | name |parent_id
---+------+---------
1  | John | 0
2  | Jane | 1
3  | James| 1
4  | Jack | 0
5  | Jim  | 4
6  | Jenny| 4
7  | Mike | 0
```

So john is parent of Jane and James. Tree goes like this.

```
John
-Jane
-James
Jack
-Jim
-Jenny
Mike
```

The difference of the question starts with Mike. Mike has no parent or child. Just somebody lonely. So When I query my table with the following query, I can't see Mike in the resultset

```
SELECT 
    t1.name as level1, t2.name as level2 
FROM 
    People as t1 
JOIN 
    People as t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
ORDER BY 
    level1, level2
```

This query brings the rows if it has child item(s) to the field level1.

Example:

```
level1 | level2
-------+-------
John   | Jane
John   | James
Jack   | Jim
Jack   | Jenny
```

How can I show Mike in the result? WHat should I change in my query?

Comment: Have you tried setting parent_id to NULL instead of 0? That might change things. Otherwise, just for the fun of it, try a RIGHT JOIN instead

Comment: Updated the 0 values to NULL, it results the same. Changed LEFT to RIGHT, nothing changed.

Comment: Weird, on MySQL 5.6 with parent_id as NULL values I get the full list of People.

Comment: @nover your are right. If I write JOIN only instead of LEFT JOIN it displays the table I have showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike has no children so just add such persons with `UNION` to your query. Also you should use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT 
        t1.name as level1, t2.name as level2 
    FROM 
        People as t1 
    JOIN 
        People as t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
    UNION
    select t1.Name as level1, '' as level2 
        from People t1 
        where Parent_id=0 
        and not exists(select 1 from People where Parent_id=t1.Id)

) People 

ORDER BY 
    level1, level2
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d111/4)